# Appcompat Toolbar "android:title" attribute not working

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I'm sure this is something very simple that I'm just overlooking. If I set the title in code it all seems to work fine:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
...
// Works fine
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("My Title");
```

Setting it in the layout xml doesn't work:

```
<!-- Doesn't work -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:title="@string/my_title"/>
```

It's worth noting I'm using the AppCompat v7 Library and testing against android sdk version 18.

Comment: Accept an answer if your problem was solved by one of the answers below.. Mine was solved by the asnwer from @adneal

Answer (score 9):

You aren't using the correct attribute. I think [the `Action Bar` docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems) explain this the best.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
    ...
</menu>
```

> **Using XML attributes from the support library**
>
> Notice that the showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace defined in the  tag. This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the Android framework on older devices. So you must use your own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support library.

In other words, you need to change `android:title` to `yourCustomPrefix:title`

```
<YourRootViewGroup xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.seeingpixels.photon"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ... >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:title="@string/my_title" />

</YourRootViewGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code?

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use follwing code for set title:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```